# how to change submorph position

Tags: smalltalk, pharo, squeak, morphic

I have two morphs that one is in the other.

```
a:= Morph new.
b:= Morph new. 
a addMorph: b. 
a openInWorld.
```

but when I want to change b's position by doing b position: 100@100, it never shows the change, so what am I missing here? or is it somehow a's responsibility to keep track of b's position?

Comment: Is `Morph` even complete enough to use it, don't you need to use a `RectangleMorph` or some other concrete subclass of `Morph`?

Comment: @Shakedown Yes, Morph is complete enough to be used directly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
| morph1 morph2 |

morph1 := Morph new.
morph1 color: Color red.
morph1 extent: 200@200.

morph2 := Morph new.
morph2 color: Color green.
morph2 extent: 50@50.

morph1 addMorph: morph2.
morph2 position: 100@100.
morph1 openInWorld.
```

The result:

[image]

Note that the positions are absolute, if you want relative positions you have to do something like:

```
morph2 position: (morph1 position + (100@100))
```

If you add Morphs to a window, you could have a look at SystemWindow #addMorph:fullFrame: which offers better possibilities to position submorphs. Morph also implements #addMorph:fullFrame: but somehow this does not seem to work for me in Pharo 2.0.

Have a look at: [Pharo collaborActive book](http://book.pharo-project.org/book/LanguageAndLibraries/GUI/PolymorphTutorial/Layout/)
and at the Basic Widgets chapter of Pharo by Example 2.